# ruby rails passenger apache2 using Basic LDAP authentication in httpd.conf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, authentication, ldap, passenger

I have a site that I want to force a user to log in via LDAP before they can see the front page of the website.  This works with generic webpages fine, but doesn't work with a rails site running passenger on apache2.  I've seen some references that this is because passenger doesn't respect the Directory command (or picks up before it gets to that directive).  Is there a way to make this happen or do I need to add devise to the site instead?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/www/software/rails_site/current/public"
    ErrorLog "/www/logs/software/rails_site/error_log"
    CustomLog "/www/logs/software/rails_site/access_log" common
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    RailsEnv production

    <Directory "/www/software/rails_site/current/public">
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Secure portal"
      AuthBasicProvider ldap
      AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
      AuthLDAPURL "info"
      AuthLDAPBindPassword "pass"
      require ldap-user usernames
      Order deny,allow
      Satisfy Any
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The above doesn't prevent the site from loading or do any challenge when first trying to load the site.

Comment: I've had a lot of success using the devise_ldap_authenticatable gem. It doesn't require any mucking around in the apache2 config file.

Answer (score 1):

Try placing the authentication directives inside a Location instead of a Directory so that they will be triggered first by the incoming URI.  Apparently Passenger has an order of operations associated with Directory directives.

This old post confirms that what you're trying to do (at least used to be) possible:

http://groups.google.com/group/phusion-passenger/browse_thread/thread/bb0ccee6b4a45bc0/429a34fb66dbde6d

Comment: Thanks for the information.  It doesn't seem to work using passenger 3.0.9 and httpd 2.2.17 using a Location directive.